# PDFView fill pdf form

Tags: java, android

I try to fill pdf form. I open and load pdf file by PDFView but how I can fill pdf form?

**I try to do this:**

```
   File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/test/ankieta.pdf");
    PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    if (file.exists()) {
        pdfView.fromFile(file)
                .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(null)
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                .spacing(0)
                .autoSpacing(false) // add dynamic spacing to fit each page on its own on the screen
                .pageSnap(true) // snap pages to screen boundaries
                .pageFling(false) // make a fling change only a single page like ViewPager
                .nightMode(false)
                .onTap(new OnTapListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTap(MotionEvent e) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .load();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First make your pdf to editable pdf.

using this site:-https://www.jotform.com/fillable-pdf-form-creator/

in this site generate a field id and save it any where because using this id you can fill pdf of fix postion of pdf and generated pdf save in `res->raw->yourpdf`

Now write this code

```
 reader = new PdfReader(current.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.form));
```

and using this code you can add in pdf

```
 PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(file, false));
                AcroFields acroFields = stamper.getAcroFields();
                acroFields.setField("name", "Hardik Talaviya");
                acroFields.setField("enroll", "150040116022");
                acroFields.setField("branch", "IT");
                acroFields.setField("sem", "8");
                stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
                stamper.close();
```

**Here name,enroll,branch and sem** is my **pdf id** which can generated when you create editable pdf.

And last save this pdf in your storage it is fill and open it where you want to open.

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Another service that can help you fill in a PDF.

www useanvil.com/developers

They have APIs for filling, generating and signing PDFs. The documentation seems pretty good and there is a prewritten node client.